# single row selection returning character vector rather than data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a loop iterating over multiple files that essentially contain an edgelist where an individual is linked to their mom. I am doing this to generate a network plot of all of the connected individuals using the igraph package.

a "tempdata" variable contains

```
         Location            ID       Dob    Sex               Mom
 1:    FS-AC-A4-Z     RAa5    R  1/1/2000 Female         RAa1    R
```

and is a data.table as shown

```
> class(tempdata)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

I then wish to create an edge-list where each individual is connected to their mom

```
> pulledCols<-c("ID","Mom")
> edgelist<-tempdata[,sapply(.SD,trimend),.SDcols=pulledCols]
```

trimend is a function defined as

```
trimend <- function(i) { # if present, get rid of the trailing whitespace and final letter
  return(ifelse(i == "","Unlisted",str_replace(i, ".([ ]+R)", "")))
}
```

however, the edgelist retrieval from tempdata returns a vector of class character (rather than a mini data.table) if only a single row is returned.

```
> class(edgelist)
[1] "character"
> edgelist
     ID       Mom 
 "RAa5"    "RAa1"
```

however, further manipulation depends on edgelist being a data.table, so I tried to recast it as such, but this doesn't seem to work

```
> setDT(edgelist)
Error in setDT(edgelist) : 
  Argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'
> as.data.table(edgelist)
   edgelist
1:      RAa5
2:      RAa1
> as.data.table(edgelist, keep.rownames=TRUE)
       rn edgelist
1:     ID      RAa5
2:    Mom      RAa1
```

okay...how about a matrix first?

```
> as.matrix(edgelist,ncol=2)
          [,1] 
ID     "RAa5"
Mom    "RAa1"
```

I also tried to melt/dcast/reshape. Melt doesn't seem right, as that's for conversion from wide to long format.

```
> dcast(as.data.table(edgelist, keep.rownames=TRUE))
Using 'edgelist' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
Error in check_formula(formula, names(data), valnames) : 
  argument "formula" is missing, with no default
> reshape(edgelist)
Error in match.arg(direction, c("wide", "long")) : 
  argument "direction" is missing, with no default
> reshape(edgelist, direction="wide")
Error in data[, timevar] : incorrect number of dimensions
...
> reshape(edgelist, varying=list(names(edgelist)), v.names=names(edgelist), direction="wide")
Error in data[, timevar] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

What can i do to get this into a one-row data.table with two columns?  Is there a way that I can prevent it from being put in a vector of class character to begin with?

Comment: Your data is not unambiguous, so it's harder to test. For me, my `edgelist` has `"RAa"` instead of your `"RAa5"`, and I don't know what you really have in `"ID"` to get that. Please post sample data using `dput(.)`, since otherwise we can only guess/speculate on what the blank space is, and have to work a little harder to actually be able to use it.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are not getting the terminal digit, given the whole field is `"RAa5    R" ` where the whitespace appears to always be spacebar characters.  The file that is read in is an excel file that has been saved as a CSV, so there shouldn't be any tab characters or other whitespaces.  But the crux of the problem is: how do I get data.table to return a data.table as a result of the selection, rather than a vector of characters?

Comment: If you start out with the following in tempdata: `tempdata<-data.table(ID="RAa5",Mom="RAa1")` and then call as above `edgelist<-tempdata[,sapply(.SD,trimend),.SDcols=c("ID","Mom")]` the class of edgelist is "character", which is not what I want.

Comment: the problem may have been my use of `sapply`, which *simplifies" whatever answer given....it is essentially changing the data.table to a more primitive type because that primitive type can hold the same information.  I'm doing some basic re-checking of the data, but it appears that using `lapply` (instead of `sapply`) gets me what I need.

Comment: Do `tempdata[,lapply(.SD,trimend),.SDcols=pulledCols]` instead of `tempdata[,sapply(.SD,trimend),.SDcols=pulledCols]`. Also, it seems that your `trimend` is not written correctly as per your description. `".([ ]+R)"` lead to the removal of an arbitrary character followed by any whitespaces followed by a character "R". For instance, `stringr::str_replace("RAa1    R", ".([ ]+R)", "")` gives me "RAa". You may want to change it to `" +R$"`

Comment: FYI, the "s" in `sapply` (whatever the *real* origin) to me means that it `s`implifies the data (ergo its default argument of `simplify="array"`). If all of the objects are the same *length*, then it does not simplify them, returning a (possibly named) `list`, but if all lengths are the same, then it does simplify them to an `"array"` which, as you can tell, will likely coerce the class of some of the columns. I try to avoid `sapply` in programmatic situations due to this, or at least force `simplify=FALSE` (which is pretty close to `lapply`).

Comment: @ekoam thanks. You are indeed correct.  I thought that the replace operation would only replace the segments that occurred within parenthetic capture groups. The replacement code that I had come up with `str_replace(i, "[.]*([ ]+R)", "")` seems to work, but is probably matching zero-or-more literal `.`s. I like the simplicity of your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer the final question

> Is there a way that I can prevent it from being put in a vector of class character to begin with?

use `lapply`, not `sapply` to apply a function to multiple columns.

Thus, the relevant line of code should be

```
    edgelist<-tempdata[,lapply(.SD,trimend),.SDcols=pulledCols]
```

Also as pointed out in the comments to the question above, I had one additional error in the code posted in the question.  My trimend function should read

```
trimend <- function(i) { # if present, get rid of the trailing whitespace and final letter
  return(ifelse(i == "","Unlisted",str_replace(i, " +R$)", "")))
}
```